# .NET 3.5 SP1 Setup Failure

Tags: windows-vista, installation, .net-3.5

I've been facing a problem that can only be described as weird for the past couple of days, while trying to install .NET 3.5 SP1 on my x64 Vista Ultimate. The problem first started while trying to install Visual Studio SP1, which I had installed before on the same machine without any issue, giving me a scrambled screen followed by  a Blue Screen saying IRQL_LESS_OR_NOT_EQUAL. I figured the scrambled screen indicated a problem with the graphics driver and I disabled it in Device Manager and tried the setup again. Then, I started getting the following error:

```
[02/14/09,16:17:27] Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (x64) (CBS): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (x64) (CBS). MSI returned error code 2 [02/14/09,16:17:57] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (x64) (CBS) is not installed.
```

I've looked around the net to find a solution and tried uninstalling .NET altogether (with a tool specifically designed for this) and reinstalling from the Visual Studio DVD, removing setup downloads from the temp directory, but nothing seems to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You stepped in a pretty big pile of doodoo, having an installation aborted without a rollback is Bad.  Try to recover your registry with a System Restore.  Before you do anything, get your machine stable first.

Comment: Well, the IRQL_LESS_OR_NOT_EQUAL thing is pretty much solved, I get no more bluescreens in the install, turns out it was a IDE Channel issue (which is creepy IMHO). Setting both drives I have master and slave on the same channel seemed to work, but the installation error is still there.